# what is the solution to different browsers rendering different content?

Tags: html

Which properties should be used and which ones to be avoided?

Comment: The solution is to not worry so much about all of them looking the same and to focus on making each one look good.

Answer (score 1):

Use the properties that are in the specification and avoid vendor specific ones.

Your question is too general to answer in specifics. Please post exactly what browsers you are talking about and what "properties" you mean.

Comment: why is clear:both property in css not working in chrome and IE?

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani - that should be a _new_ question from you, not a comment to my answer.

Comment: I cant post questions in less than 20 minutes

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani - Are you in such a hurry?

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani - Look at this page. It won't answer the why (since that's something only the creators of the browsers can answer), but can give you workarounds: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: @Chandan Khatwani - Seeing as StackOverflow is _free_, I don't believe anyone has the right to expect _quick_ answers. No one who answers questions here gets paid for it.

Comment: @Chandan that is humbug. `clear: both` works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at meyer's work : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

He provided a CSS sheet that minimized browsers differences. It's about what browsers consider "default value" for some css properties.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware about the reset css. It does work for resetting margins.

Answer (score 0):

you should be avoiding from building non-standards html,

which means it's very recommended to built according to the latest web-standards,

today all the modern browsers(firefox,opera,chrome,safary,ie8+) are build to support the [xhtml Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/), 
you also can check your browser Compatibility with the [acid 2](http://www.webstandards.org/action/acid2/) or [acid 3](http://acid3.acidtests.org/) test,

you may also want to check out your html in [xhtml validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check the markup and stick to the standards,